Craft Commerce 5: Displaying Additional Shipping Method Details
In Craft Commerce 5, when selecting a shipping method, I list the available options using cart.availableShippingMethodOptions like this:
{% for handle, method in cart.availableShippingMethodOptions %}
    Method: {{ method.name }}
    Price: {{ method.getPrice() | commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
{% endfor %}

However, I would like to display more details about each available shipping method, including:

Listing the corresponding Shipping Rule.
Displaying the Shipping Rule description.
Describing the "Match Order" criteria in plain text.

In my project, for example, I have two available methods:

Click & Collect
Delivery

I would like to specify the following details, ideally defined directly from the shipping method configuration (without using Globals or hardcoding text):

Click & Collect:

Shipping Rule Description: Collection is possible during our store's business days.
Match Order: Always free (Base Rate Cost = 0).


Delivery:

Shipping Rule Description: Free delivery for orders over €100.
Match Order: Free for orders over €100 (Base Rate Cost = 7 / Match Order: Total price is less than €100).



What is the most appropriate way to retrieve and display these additional details for each shipping method?

To get the general shipping rule when you have the shipping method:
{% for handle, method in cart.availableShippingMethodOptions %}
  ...
  {% set rule = method.getMatchingShippingRule(cart) %}
  {% if rule %}
    {{ rule.name }} 
  {% endif %}
  ...
{% endfor %}

to get some property of the order conditions rules something like this would likely be it:
{% set condition = rule.orderCondition.conditionRules|filter(item => item is instance of ('craft\\commerce\\elements\\conditions\\orders\\ShippingAddressZoneConditionRule'))|first %}

{% if condition %}
   
    Shipping zone IDs in this condition rule: {{ condition.getValues()|join(',') }} 
{% else %}
    {# No condition of the specified class was found #}
    <p>No ShippingAddressZoneConditionRule found.</p>
{% endif %}

in php something like this
$rule = Plugin::getInstance()->getShippingRules()->getAllShippingRules()[0];
$condition = collect($rule->getOrderCondition()->getConditionRules())
    ->firstWhere(fn($item) => $item instanceof craft\commerce\elements\conditions\orders\ShippingAddressZoneConditionRule);
$zoneIds = $condition->getValues();

Hope that helps.

Great! Is it possible to translate the rule name and description from the CP? I run a multilingual shop.
